# Is it possible to only install specific functions from a package and the functions they depend on in R?

Tags: r, function, package

I am using quite a few packages but I only need a few functions from each package. The packages are quite large. Is there a way to only install specific functions and only the functions they require? I have built a software package and I have been having users install all the dependency packages as a part of it — which is largely unnecessary.

My alternative is translating to base R which I don’t really want to do if I can help it!

Thank you

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the answer is no, you cannot install parts of packages. How large is "quite large"? Most R packages are only a few megabytes or less compressed, unless they contain large amounts of data. I would not be concerned that storage is an issue on modern computers, from an R package perspective.

Comment: I'm not sure that the linked question + answer is a duplicate of this one. The linked questions asks whether individual functions can be loaded from an installed package; this question asks whether only parts of a package can be installed. Although the explanation would be similar in both cases.

Comment: Exactly. The answer regardless, is no.